# JMS + WildFly 8.2.0 - Reading from remote jms queue

Tags: java, jms, hornetq, wildfly-8, jboss-mdb

I'm trying to read messages from a remote jms queue located on remote server, also on WildFly 8.2.0.
The remote queue name defined on remote server is "java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/grinderRemote".

I defined a queue on the read server with the same name, but I'm not sure that it's correct.

For read message I created a Dynamic Web Project with MDB class. The code is below

```
package it.vr.pms;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;


@MessageDriven(name = "ReadJMS1", activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "/exported/jms/queue/grinderRemote"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"), 
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "user", propertyValue = "jmsuser"), 
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "password", propertyValue = "********"),
    //@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "connectorClassName", propertyValue = "org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory"),
    //@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "useJNDI", propertyValue = "false"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "connectionParameters", propertyValue = "host=http-remoting://192.168.5.124;port=8080")})
public class ReadJMS1 implements MessageListener {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ReadJMS1.class.toString());


    public void onMessage(Message rcvMessage) {
        TextMessage msg = null;
        try {
            if (rcvMessage instanceof TextMessage) {
                msg = (TextMessage) rcvMessage;
                System.out.println("Received Message from queue: " + msg.getText());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Message of wrong type: " + rcvMessage.getClass().getName());
            }
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The "reader" server log is the following:

```
10:26:10,273 INFO  [org.hornetq.ra] (default-threads - 1) HQ151000: awaiting topic/queue creation /exported/jms/queue/grinderRemote
10:26:10,336 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017534: Registered web context: /TestJMSReceive
10:26:10,492 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS018559: Deployed "TestJMSReceiveEAR.ear" (runtime-name : "TestJMSReceiveEAR.ear")
10:26:10,836 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990/management
10:26:10,836 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990
10:26:10,836 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: WildFly 8.2.0.Final "Tweek" started in 9312ms - Started 326 of 386 services (112 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
10:26:12,304 INFO  [org.hornetq.ra] (default-threads - 1) HQ151001: Attempting to reconnect org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQActivationSpec(ra=org.hornetq.ra.HornetQResourceAdapter@48b7ee22 destination=/exported/jms/queue/grinderRemote destinationType=javax.jms.Queue ack=Auto-acknowledge durable=false clientID=null user=jmsuser password=**** maxSession=15)
```

I can't understand where I'm wrong.
I also tried using the commented @ActivationConfigProperty but the result was the same...

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I did the configuration suggested by apocalypz but the error is the following now:

```
15:25:47,116 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS014142: Started message driven bean 'ReadJMS1' with 'hornetq-ra.rar' resource adapter
15:25:47,163 WARN  [org.hornetq.ra] (default-threads - 1) HQ152005: Failure in HornetQ activation org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQActivationSpec(ra=org.hornetq.ra.HornetQResourceAdapter@71996bda destination=queue/LocalServer1Q destinationType=javax.jms.Queue ack=Auto-acknowledge durable=false clientID=null user=null maxSession=15): javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jms/RemoteConnectionFactory -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jms.RemoteConnectionFactory
```

Seems it tries to use resource adapter hornetq-ra instead of RemoteConnectionFactory. Or it cannot found RemoteConnectionFactory on the other server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure RemoteConnectionFactory on server with MDB (inside wildfly config you are currently using, e.g. standalone-full.xml), then set it via 'connectionFactoryLookup' property. Destination does not need to be in jboss/exported ns.

```
@MessageDriven(name = "RemoteQueueConsumer", 
activationConfig = { 
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "java:jboss/jms/queue/RemoteQueue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "connectionFactoryLookup", propertyValue = "java:jboss/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"),              
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "user", propertyValue = "user1"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "password", propertyValue = "pwd.123"),  
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "messageSelector", propertyValue = "messageType=testMessage") 
})
```

For RemoteConnectionFactory configuration you must point ConnectionFactory to Connector, which has reference to outbound-socket-binding.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone need other solution using Wildfly (Jboss), This post give another example

[@ResoucerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33375133/1223901)